# How can I display same content in another tab of one tab in tab control?

Tags: c#

I am using button to add the second tab in tab control. And want to display all content of tab 1 in tab2 when it open by button click.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: No code No Fun...lol...

Comment: @Patel Correct.@Kinjal Are You using web forms? if so search for panels i think that is what you want.

Comment: what exactly you want ? e.g. current address you type and it will copy to permanent address ? in web forms ?

Comment: it is possible to display Same Content for all TabItems in TabControl.. i am workin in winform.

Comment: There's no such thing as "a tab" in C#, what are you talking about, mvc? web forms? wpf? wcf? What project type? We can't help you with so little information so 1) tell us exactly what project you are using (and add the relevant tags to your post) and 2) post some code of what you currently have.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau: he said in a comment before yours that it's about winforms

Answer (score 0):

You should create a simple **[UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)** which will have all required controls and the logic that handles that controls. Once you have that, you can simply add that control to each TabPage you create.

If you want to copy all the controls from one TabPage to another, what you are looking for is '**Cloning**'. Take a look at the search result for this keywords: **[c# clone tabpage](https://www.google.hr/search?newwindow=1&q=c#%20clone%20tabpage&oq=c#%20clone%20tabpage&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.269994.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..45.serp..0.0.0.QDGayuaVOD4)**

I would go with the first approach because the result is more cleaner.... if you will clone your controls, you need to make sure that you handle all the cloned controls events... which could get kind of messy.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty question, you'll get quick and dirty answer:

```
    private void duplicateTab()
    {
        // Your TabControl Name
        TabPage selectedTab = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

        TabPage newTab = new TabPage();
        foreach (Control ctrl in selectedTab.Controls)
        {
            Control newCtrl = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(ctrl.GetType());

            PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(ctrl);

            foreach (PropertyDescriptor proDe in pdc)
            {
                object val = proDe.GetValue(ctrl);
                proDe.SetValue(newCtrl, val);
            }

            newTab.Text = "New Tab";
            newTab.Controls.Add(newCtrl);

        }
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTab);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to be real upset with yourself when you see how easy this is...

```
    private void NewTab_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgse)
    {
         var tab1 = new TabItem();
         tab1.Header = "New Tab";
         tab1.Content = [name of tab to copy].Content;
         [name of tab control].Items.Add(tab1);
    }
```

Here is my code:

```
    private void NewTab_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         var tab1 = new TabItem();
         tab1.Header = "New Tab";
         tab1.Content = tabitem1.Content;
         TabControl1.Items.Add(tab1);
    }
```